# php remove \ before double quote

Tags: php, escaping, quotes

Why does the following work for removing a \ before a single quote but not a double quote?

UPDATE:  the code below works but not when the single ' or " iss in the first position.  Is there a way to fix that?

Input is coming from a form where I have no control of what people type in.

```
 $x[0] = $_POST['line1'];
   $x[1] = $_POST['line2'];
   $x[2] = $_POST['place'];



   //check for apostrophes and quotes
   for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
      while( strpos($x[$i], "\'") != false){
          $pos = strpos($x[$i], "\'");
          $x[$i] = substr_replace($x[$i],"",$pos,1);
      }
      while( strpos($x[$i], '\"') != false){
          $pos = strpos($x[$i], '\"');
          $x[$i] = substr_replace($x[$i],"",$pos,1);
      }
```

Comment: You could also replace your inner loops by just saying replace them with just the quotes... `$x[$i] = str_replace(["\\\"","\'"], ['"', "'"], $x[$i]);`

Comment: Just checked and `for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){ $x[$i] = str_replace(["\\\"","\'"], ['"', "'"], $x[$i]);}` seems to work

Comment: sorry about that. I tried again and it works like a charm.  also your marked as duplicate is right on.  I changed != to !== and that also works.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the PHP manual -

Single quoted ¶
The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes (the character `'`).

To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

That should answer your question.

Comment: no, it really doesn't answer the question at all.  Please see updated question